Can't find any Bluetooth devices
I can't connect any bluetooth device to my Raspberry Pi 3, because it simply doesn't list the devices:

I checked the peripherials that I wanted to connect to my pi, and they are discoverable by my phone, PC etc. except the PI.
The OS version that installed on the PI is the following:
Operating System: Raspbian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Kernel: Linux 6.6.31+rpt-rpi-v7
and it is the 32bit version.
The only modification that I did with the os was to install blueman and pi-bluetooth packages, otherwise it was a fresh install.
I did some research and tried a few things:
checked if the bluetooth overlay is disabled and it's not
KalinkaComputer@KalinkaComputer:~ $ grep -v -E "^(#.*)?$" /boot/firmware/config.txt
dtparam=audio=on
camera_auto_detect=1
display_auto_detect=1
auto_initramfs=1
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2
disable_fw_kms_setup=1
disable_overscan=1
arm_boost=1
[cm4]

bluetooth service seems running:
sudo systemctl status bluetooth

● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service

     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-06-09 10:54:20 CEST; 1min 10s ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 660 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 1556)
        CPU: 209ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─660 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jun 09 10:54:20 KalinkaComputer bluetoothd[660]: Bluetooth daemon 5.66
Jun 09 10:54:20 KalinkaComputer systemd[1]: Started bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service.
Jun 09 10:54:20 KalinkaComputer bluetoothd[660]: Starting SDP server
Jun 09 10:54:20 KalinkaComputer bluetoothd[660]: profiles/audio/vcp.c:vcp_init() D-Bus experimental >
Jun 09 10:54:20 KalinkaComputer bluetoothd[660]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() Failed to init vcp plugin
Jun 09 10:54:20 KalinkaComputer bluetoothd[660]: profiles/audio/mcp.c:mcp_init() D-Bus experimental >
Jun 09 10:54:20 KalinkaComputer bluetoothd[660]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() Failed to init mcp plugin
Jun 09 10:54:20 KalinkaComputer bluetoothd[660]: profiles/audio/bap.c:bap_init() D-Bus experimental >
Jun 09 10:54:20 KalinkaComputer bluetoothd[660]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() Failed to init bap plugin
Jun 09 10:54:20 KalinkaComputer bluetoothd[660]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized

none of the RF devices are blocked:
KalinkaComputer@KalinkaComputer:~ $ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no

but no devices are detected:
    KalinkaComputer@KalinkaComputer:~ $ hcitool dev
Devices:

and no default controller either:
    KalinkaComputer@KalinkaComputer:~ $ bluetoothctl devices
No default controller available

How to solve this issue?

Kinda' weird... maybe start by deleting the blueman and pi-bluetooth packages, and start over? Also, an older question, or this blog may help?

I think you have to reinstall Bluetooth-related packages.

I tried with an entirely new OS image that was only updated after the boot, no additional packages, just the updates. Still nothing is detected, and when I use the bluetoothctl and turn on the scan mode, the error message presist: "No default controller avaiable"

So it seems that the root cause is some kind of a hardware problem according to a Raspberry Pi engineer.  Raspberry Pi forum answer
